Customizing time zone with TaskScheduler.getClock()
From the documentation of CronTrigger(String expression, ZoneId zoneId):

Note that such explicit time zone customization is usually not necessary, using TaskScheduler.getClock() instead.

What is that supposed to mean? You can't set the ZoneId of a Clock.

I think that's the point - usually, you don't need to set the timezone and in that case, you can use TaskScheduler.getClock().

In that case, one could use the constructor without the ZoneId parameter.
